# Sound output device is lost on suspend, requiring a reboot to reactivate

Tags: sound, suspend, pulseaudio, hdmi, system-settings

I'm listening to YouTube Music (in Google-Chrome in Flatpak) and walk away for 10 minutes.  My desktop turns the screen blank to save power, as I told it to:

[image: Screen Blank: 10 minutes]

Sometimes the music stops and sometimes it keeps playing after a 1-second cutout.  That's, annoying, but not my biggest issue.  If it stops, I wake it up and sign back in.  Still no sound.  Open "Settings: Sound" and it says Output Device: "Digital Output (S/PDIF) - Built-in Audio".  There are no other options in the drop-down:

[image: Output Device: S/PDIF]

**Expected**

1. Sound should not stop (for more than a second) when screen goes into power-save mode.
2. After waking the screen, HDMI output device should be restored, not lost.
3. If output device is lost, it should be quickly re-detect and offer the device as an option in Sound Settings.
4. Since no optical or S/PDIF cable is present, that option should not be auto-selected.

Similarly, if I turn on my computer before my amp, I have to reboot to get it to recognize the HDMI 5.1 and produce any sound.

**Possible solutions**

- Uninstall pulseaudio and install pipewire instead? I tried and failed (see below)
- Can I set my audio system to default to HDMI 5.1 Surround?

**Equipment**

- Amp: DENON AVR-S500BT
- Ubuntu 22.04
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K CPU @
  4.00GHz
- Gigabyte GA-Z97X-UD3H-BK Motherboard
- Desktop-to-amp connection: HDMI cable.  Monitor signal also goes through this cable
- Amp-to-monitor connection: HDMI to DVI cable

**Tried: Restarting Pulseaudio**

This post is not a duplicate of [Ubuntu 20.04 missing hdmi sound device after monitor goes to sleep mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1294939/ubuntu-20-04-missing-hdmi-sound-device-after-monitor-goes-to-sleep-mode)

- `pulseaudio -k` and `systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service` do not restore the device to the list (don't do anything as far as I can see).
- I seem to have both pipewire and pulseaudio installed?  Did that happen from using Flatpak on Ubuntu?

**Tried: Replacing Pulseaudio with Pipewire**

```
sudo apt install pipewire
systemctl --user --now disable pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket
sudo apt purge pulseaudio*
sudo apt autoremove
```

Rebooted and no sound devices appeared in the list and no sound comes out.

```
sudo apt install pulseaudio
```

Rebooted and it defaulted to HDMI as it should.
[image]

I have the same problem as soon as it suspends.

**Tried: Replacing Pulseaudio with Pipewire AGAIN**

This time I followed the instructions here:
https://linux.how2shout.com/enable-pipewire-for-audio-and-bluetooth-in-ubuntu-22-04-or-20-04/

Achieved: "Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.48)" but I need to let it burn in to test it.

**Tried: Give it S/PDIF (since it seems to want that)**

Optical sound uses lossy compression, but I bought a S/PDIF cable, but it didn't work.  I can't remember now if that means "no sound" (probably) or "no 5.1 option."  I've used an optical cable successfully with another system for years.